# Libgdx sprite not drawing in browser

Tags: java, gwt, libgdx

This is the first time I'm trying to deploy a libgdx game to html but having some difficulties.

On desktop everything works fine, but in browser two of my sprites are not showing up, the rest is fine.

These two sprites should be backgrounds and scrolling why the character moves.

I'm loading my textures in a GameScree class' show method like this:

```
backgroundTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.png"));

//setting wraping to repeat to achive scrolling background by one texture
backgroundTexture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat);

//and I render it like this (I create a Sprite of it)
batch.draw(backgroundSprite.getTexture(),0,0, (int) position ,0, 1280, 720);
```

By increasing position the background is scrolling which works fine on desktop.

I got errors in chromes console:

[.Offscreen-For-WebGL-00000000071AC350]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.

Which I don't exactly understand why, how is it incompatible? And also, none of my texture are POT but they are still working.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using mipmaps when texture is not power of 2.

```
backgroundTexture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
```

It's better to use texture is in power of 2 (pixel width and height are some 2<sup>n</sup> value)

Comment: Thank you, yes I know non pot textures are better in general, but none of my textures are power of two and they are still working. Also if I'm right, you can enable mipmaping of a texture by passing true as the second parameter to Textures constructor and I'm not doing that. I've added Linear filtering on this particular texture but its not showing.